# in Unix concatenation of two variables

Tags: unix

i have a file C20140728 I want a variable which will store C and other varibale which will store 20140728(here second variable is current systemdate in %Y%m%d format) and third variable when I echo should concatenatae and show C20140728

Comment: What does "unix" mean?

Comment: using shell script i mean to say

Comment: @user3867974 What's your OS or distro? What version is your shell?

Comment: if the `C` is fixed, does this line help you? `date +"C%Y%m%d"`

Comment: Yes it worked but when i use ls its throwing error.please check below error                                                           #!/bin/sh
str=“C”
NOW=$(date +”C%Y%m%d.txt”)
echo $NOW
ls -ltr $NOW                                                                here ls is showing below error                                          ls: ”C20140729.txt”: No such file or directory

Comment: it worked thank you all for help

Answer (score 1):

In general to concatenate two variables you can just write them one after another:

```
a='C'
b='20140728'
c=$a$b
```

edit:
to get the current date

```
b = $(date +'%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: sorry the second variable is current date in a %Y%m%d format

Comment: edited the answer. hope that helps

Comment: while i write echo $c it showing “C””20140729” but i want it show one value C20140729

Comment: #!/bin/sh
str=“C”
NOW=$(date +”%Y%m%d”)
str2=$str$NOW
echo $str2                                                                      this is the code which i have wrote in test.sh file

Comment: just replace the double quotes with single quotes!

Comment: no spaces allowed around `=` char as in your `b = $(date ..`. Good luck to all.